# How to rename a Blazor WebAssembly solution and its projects

Tags: blazor-webassembly, visual-studio-2019

I taken a sample vs2019 Blazor WASM (Hosted) solution and renamed the solution and its projects (Client,Server,Shared) and it runs fine but if I open the Console I see:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status 404 (not found) on this:
"*oldprojectname*.Client.styles.css:1"  (image below)
Where is the solution/project getting this "oldprojectname" from?  I've scanned the entire source of the project and deleted the .vs files and still it has this "*oldprojectname*"
What am I missing? Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yet another thing that I can't explain but if you experienced the above then simply switching the "applicationUrl" port number resolved my problems.
This can be found in the launchSettings.json in both the Client and Server project.

Answer (score 1):

Check the Head section of wwwroot/index.html of the Client project

Comment: That file doesn't exist in an Blazor wasm project (hosted)

Comment: Sorry. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution in my opinion to rename projects (as per the question) is the following:

You can export the project as a "Template" and Visual Studio can let you re-create the project exactly how it was when you created the template, and then you can give the project a new name. :)

[image]